# How do I set up an OpenGL programming environment?

Tags: programming, graphics, opengl

I want to setup openGL programming environment on ubuntu. What packages or tools I should install and what is the best way of getting into openGL as a newbie.

Comment: What language would you prefer?

Comment: Please click [edit] and then update your question to specify the programming language you wish to use. OpenGL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL is not a language, and you need to specify one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackOverflow is a better place for programming related questions, check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859501/learning-opengl-in-ubuntu

Comment: Ironically, the question you linked to was closed as off-topic. ;)

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know OpenGL is a graphics library. The IDE choice depends on the language you want use OpenGL in.

[Anjuta](http://packages.ubuntu.com/anjuta) is a perfect IDE for C and C++

```
sudo apt-get install anjuta
```

then you have to download OpenGL library:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

after that you should include libraries (in folder gl/*) into your code

Comment: +1. GLUT is what we learned on for graphics at uni. Fairly standard C bindings and there's lots of documentation.