# cmake Error installing OpenCASCADE

Tags: compiling, git, opengl, cmake

I came across an error trying to install OpenCASCADE (oce) using `cmake`, where I was following the build command:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DOCE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/you/want/oce ..
make install
```

I downloaded OpenCASCADE with: `git clone git://github.com/tpaviot/oce.git` from https://www.dealii.org/8.3.0/external-libs/opencascade.html

The command line build error is:

```
-- Build 64bit
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:172 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:440 (find_package)
```

I checked to see if I had a version of OpenGL, with,

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

that showed:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

So it seems I have `OpenGL` but the build cannot find it.
Can anyone understand how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been solved by installing a development version of `OpenGL`, following the link at:

[How do I set up an OpenGL programming environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11378/how-do-i-set-up-an-opengl-programming-environment)

and installing the files: `sudo apt-get install anjuta`

`sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev`
(includes opengl dev though under different names, as I undertstand it)

I also needed the development version of freetype by using:

`sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` , from last comment at:

[freetype cannot be found by build #3029](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/)

Now OpenCASCADE is building correctly.